# Steam and file explorer do not open

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, steam

Just loaded up my computer and tried to access steam via the task bar (windows 10), the icon flashes, the "updating steam" loading bar comes up and then it goes orange. But steam doesn't open. if i hover over the task bar icon the small window comes up which shows it's open but i cant seem to actually open it up. i tried to fix this problem via my file explorer built that has encountered the exact same problem. i can still open everything else normally as far as i am aware (haven't tested thoroughly). Anyone have any ideas?
Alex

Comment: Have you rebooted your machine since this happened?

Comment: yeah, that's the first thing i tried

Comment: Neither appear in task view but both appear in task manager when i have attempted to open them.

Comment: How do you mean about File Explorer not opening? Explorer.exe is used for all of your directory listing windows, as well as handling the task bar and start menu. Does your task bar still behave as normal?

Comment: File explorer appears to run normally, but no window ever appears for me to use. my task seems fine and i can run other programs from it, such as my mail and google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Backup your steamapps(that is the exact name, no spaces) folder and then reinstall Steam. Restore steamapps folder and Steam should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this was posted ages ago but i want to put this in for new people with this problem. I had the exact same trouble as stated in the question. What happened for me is that for some reason (unknown to me) windows had decided that i now have two displays and had to extend my desktop over to this non-existent screen of mine. Steam and the file explorer would both open on this magical second screen. Basically all you do is right click on your desktop, hit screen resolution and set Display as the screen you are using and mess around with the multiple displays thing until you get your full desktop back (for me i had to set it to Show desktop only on 2....don't ask why). Once you have done this you should get steam and the file explorer back and even a few shortcuts that decided they like the magical screen of non-existence better than your actual screen. Now if you would excuse me i'm off to reinstall steam because someone (not naming any names) said that steam had to be uninstalled and reinstalled.